# How would karma work in this case?

Tags: karma

Suppose someone speaks some bad thing to you, it breaks your heart, you feel bad, you cry. That someone accumulated bad karma.

You remember 2 months later that this person had said it to you. You cry again and feel bad , feel heart-broken. Will that person who spoke ill to you get bad karma again just because you remembered the insult and felt bad ? or would it be only 1 time bad karma for him ?

Comment: No. He won't incur bad karma again.. It was just one time for him. Also it is your bad karma that you felt bad first time as well as again

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by "Also it is your...." @ArtistFormerlyKnownAsCSD

Comment: It is your bad karma from past actions (including actions done in past births) that resulted in you getting hurt in this birth. This is your prarabdh karma. While that someone who did actions to hurt you is incurring Kriyamana Karma for himself @LSSJBroly

Comment: Okay..but I don't think this is what karma cycle says. Like if it's true then..this person's kriyamana karma will one day become prarabdha...then that person will also suffer from a different person let's say C. Then C incurs kriyamana karma..and suffers from D and cycle continues. Isn't it what you're saying? Correct me if I'm wrong. @ArtistFormerlyKnownAsCSD

Comment: And why it isn't possible that if I get hurt, then it's my kriyamana nd not my prarabdha. How can we be so sure that me getting hurt was prarabdha and not kriyamana? Maybe it was new karma that took place in me getting hurt. @ArtistFormerlyKnownAsCSD

Comment: When did I say that you getting hurt was your kriyamana. That is your prarabdha. And yes the person who caused you hurt has incurred kriyamana Karma that will fructify during his prarabdha @LSSJBroly

Comment: You said prarabdha only. Read carefully. Actually u didn't get my question. I'm basically asking that does this 'hurting other' cycle continue forever? A has hurt B, then as a result B incurred kriyamana karma and he will get hurt by C and then C wil get hurt by D. Isn't it you're trying to say? So I am asking does the law of karma work like this? If yes then will this 'hurting others' continue forever? @ArtistFormerlyKnownAsCSD

Comment: And my 2nd q. was... how can we be so sure that me getting hurt was my Prarabdha. Like how because of my prarabdha only I got hurt. Why can't I get hurt because of kriyamana. Maybe the incident where hurting took place was altogether new and was part of my kriyamana and as well as kriyamana of the other person who hurt me. It may be kriyamana who knows? @ArtistFormerlyKnownAsCSD

Comment: It can be Kriyamana fructifying if part of same birth. But you can't tell the bad karma you have incurred is your prarabdha (previous birth) or Kriyamana (past actions of this birth)@LSSJBroly

Comment: Yes ............

Answer (score 0):

If someone speaks bad, that means his heart/citta is poisonous. One is diseased if anger, pride, lust, self-pitty etc exist within oneself. With such serpents lurking in one's heart, one will get bitten from time to time. So internally he/she will always be in turmoil.

It is also said if you pray for somebody then that adds to his wellbeing and if you curse it adds to his bad karma.

But a wise person will neither curse nor praise another, understanding that whatever happens to one is one's doing. Taking full responsibility in such a way, knowing the play of maya, he will purify his existence with Sadhana.

The so called bad thing has already happened. So why repeat the incident after two months again? Why create more bad karma for yourself? Let go of the thorn.

Hope this help :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In Karma, there is nothing like good and bad karma. Karma is all about cause and effect. Someone speaks some bad, then 'speaking bad' is the cause and it effects himself internally (body and mind). Even thought he is not aware of it.
Someone else keeps remembering the same fact again and again. Here 'recalling/remmebering' is the cause, which effects again and that effect would be the cause for someother effect. And the chaining goes on. A wise person, shall do good action (cause) so that it effects are good for himself.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Sinful acts have been classified into three groups viz- sins committed by thoughts (mind), sins committed by speech and lastly bodily sins.

> Manu Smriti 12.5. Coveting the property of others, thinking in one’s
> heart of what is undesirable, and adherence to false (doctrines), are
> the three kinds of (sinful) mental action.
>
> 12.6. Abusing (others, speaking) untruth, detracting from the merits of all men, and talking idly, shall be the four kinds of (evil) verbal
> action.
>
> 12.7. Taking what has not been given, injuring (creatures) without the sanction of the law, and holding criminal intercourse with another
> man’s wife, are declared to be the three kinds of (wicked) bodily

In the above verses, 12.5 enumerates sins of thoughts, 12.6 sins committed by speech and 12.7 sins committed through bodily actions.

The case you have mentioned falls under the second category or sin committed through verbal action.

Now, for all these sins punishments are clearly mentioned in the same scripture.

> 12.9. In consequence of (many) sinful acts committed with his body, a man becomes (in the next birth) something inanimate, **in consequence
> (of sins) committed by speech, a bird, or a beast,** and in
> consequence of mental (sins he is re-born in) a low caste.

So the punishment for verbal abuse is becoming a bird or beast in the next life. Since this is an one time punishment so it can not be that every time the person cries remembering his insult the offender receives new bad Karmas. He has committed bad verbal Karma only once when he insulted and for which he will be punished once only.

Comment: Are mental and verbal sins for kaliyug too?Because like even if I don't think bad people around me will force me to think bad. If I don't want to abuse then people will abuse me. I think these are till Dwaparyug

Comment: Sins by thought can not be performed in Kali Yuga .. the remaining sins are all there @Hope